# Using ggtree to color tips of phylogenetic tree

Tags: r, ggtree

I have very limited experience coding so please bear with me!

I have a newick tree and a .txt file with various cell numbers assigned to various clone numbers, shown here:

[image: List]

I've followed the steps from the [PHE: Bioinformatics](https://phe-bioinformatics.github.io/blog/2017/07/07/ggtree_part2) page and all I am getting is one color on all of the tips, not seeming to categorize the cells by Clone number.

Here is an image of the resulting plot:

[image: Output]

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggtree")
nwk <- ("/Users/Nisu/Downloads/True.nwk")
tree <- read.tree(nwk)
p <- ggtree(tree,right = TRUE)
tip_metadata <- read.table("/Users/Nisu/Downloads/TallG5clone_50_9_True_cloneAnno.txt", sep="\t",col.names = c("Clone", "Cell"),header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE, stringsAsFactor=F)
p <- p %<+% tip_metadata + geom_tippoint(aes(color= "Clone"), size=3)
plot(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely because you added quotation marks to `"Clone"`. Variables in the data should not be quoted. It should be therefore `geom_tippoint(aes(color= Clone)`.
Here is an example: Adding the aes `colour = class` without quotation marks:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now with quotation marks:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = "class")) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I thought that as well, but whenever I removed the quotation marks I received the following error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Clone' not found

Comment: Sorry to bother, but @ViviG do you possibly know why I’m still getting the object not found error?

Comment: It is really hard to tell because I can't reproduce your example. Is it possible for you to share your files?

Comment: Yes here is a link to a dropbox with both files mentioned in my example: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u94t2y67yiqzspl/AACuv6OumTHTqtDC5SVVF9f7a?dl=0